# Remove ViewController from Segue Stack

Tags: objective-c, segue

I am currently calling viewControllers to be displayed with this code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"main" sender:self];
```

and dismissing with this code:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Which works great for just displaying and dismissing one view at a time.  The problem I am facing is that I have two view controllers stacked on top of the main controller, and I want to dismiss the middle one before the top one so when I dismiss the top one it animates and shows the main controller.

What should I do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't so that by dismissing the middle one first, you have the main controller do the dismissal, and it will dismiss both controllers at the same time with an animation that will only show the last one going to main (you won't see any intervening ones no matter how many there are). So, from that second controller, you can use self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController to access the main controller:

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked great, and I appreciate your help!